# Cannot convert from 'CodingStandardsImprovement.MainProgram.MainConversion' to 'System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window'

Tags: c#

Receiving this on a message box, I am using the MetroFramework in attempt to display a message box however I am receiving this error(CS1503).

```
            while (true)
            {

                try
                {
                    Var.borrowAmountNumber = int.Parse(borrowAmount);
                    Var.loanLengthNumber = int.Parse(loanLength);
                    Var.interestRateNumber = float.Parse(interestRate);
                    Var.i = true;
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Please enter a integer.","Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning,100);

                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is your application WPF? MetroFramework is for WinForms. `WPF != WinForms`. Also this will not work if `MainCoversion` is not a form, hence, the error. Pass null instead.

Comment: The application is on WinForms, the fix for this was replacing this at the start of the message box with `Form.ActiveForm` instead of `this`

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

Replace:
 `MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Please enter a integer.","Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning,100);`

With:
`MetroMessageBox.Show(Form.ActiveForm, "Please enter a integer.","Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning,100);`

This fixes the issue.